# Read csv - R reads just one column

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to open .csv file and it is comma separated, but this line doesn't seem to work:

data2020 <-  read.csv("F:/data/data2020M1.csv",header = TRUE, sep=",")

this is what I got:
[image]

when using fread I get this error:
File is encoded in UTF-16, this encoding is not supported by fread(). Please recode the file to UTF-8.

Comment: Your file may be saved in like UTF-16 format or something weird. I just encountered this myself recently.

Comment: and how did you fix it?

Comment: if that is the case, use the argument `encoding = ...`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the top few lines of the raw CSV file, perhaps there's something obvious we can see.

Comment: I opened mine in libreoffice, and saved using UTF-8 encoding instead.